# Using Javascript to dynamically add a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to dynamically add a text box using javascript. I have ingredients and quantity which I want to be able to continue to add upon clicking add ingredients.

My Javascript looks like this:

```
$('.recipe-ingredients #addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
        var i = $('.recipe-ingredients .ingredient').size() + 1;
        $('<div class="form-group ingredient"><label class="control-label" for="searchinput">Ingredients</label><div><input id="ingredient_' + i + '" name="ingredients[]" type="text" placeholder="Ingredients" class="form-control input-md"></div></div><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pure-button pure-u-1-6 pure-button-primary" id="addNewIngredient">Add Ingredient</a></div>').appendTo($('.recipe-ingredients .ingredients'));
        $('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="buttondropdown">Quantity</label><div class="input-group"><input id="quantity_' + i + '" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" type="text"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Measure<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown pull-right"><li><a href="#">Grams</a></li><li><a href="#">Ounces</a></li><li><a href="#">Option three</a></li></ul></div></div>').appendTo($'.recipe-quantities .quantities'));
```

When loading the page I get a console error which says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Please could someone advise to me as to what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`.appendTo($'.recipe-quantities .quantities')`

perhaps you meant `.appendTo($('.recipe-quantities .quantities'))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. If you look at the code I actually have double brackets already, so I don't think its that.

Comment: I think Lucas meant the opening paren after the `$`

Comment: Yes. You have a `$` directly followed by a quote with no parethesis